# FileAttributes to ImageSource: IValueConverter not working

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

So, I made a "tiny" file explorer page inside my music player (Universal App) and I need to place an image informing wheter is is Directory or file. But the code isn't working.
This is converter itself: namespace myApp before its own namespace.

```
namespace Converters
{
    public sealed class AttributesToImageConverter : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert ( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
        {
            FileAttributes f = (FileAttributes)value;
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage img = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage ( );
            img.DecodePixelWidth = 50;
            if ( f == FileAttributes.Directory )
            {
                img.UriSource = new Uri ( "ms-appx:/Asstes/folder.png", UriKind.Absolute );
            }
            else
                img.UriSource = new Uri ( "ms-appx:/Asstes/file.png", UriKind.Absolute );
            return img;
        }

        public object ConvertBack ( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ( );
        }
    }
}
```

This is XAML:

```
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:converter="using:myApp.Converters" >

    <Page.Resources>
        <converter:AttributesToImageConverter x:Key="AttributesToImageConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    ...
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="">
    ...
        <ListView x:Name="ContentRoot" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" Height="500" Margin="10,-10,10,15" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,2,2,2">
                        <Image Width="50" Height="50" Margin="5,0,5,0" Source="{Binding Attributes, Converter={StaticResource AttributesToImageConverter}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    ...
    </Grid>
```

Other Bindings to this context work, binding to Name property in the same IStorageItem works perfectly, this one doesn't. Additionally, using ListView causes the app to shutdown few seconds AFTER displaying the loaded data without any debug information or exception but code -2147483645 (0x80000003). I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: you need to return an image source not an image

Answer (score 0):

Is "Attributes" an actual property for each item within ItemsSource "List" or is it a separate property within your view-model?

Create a storage file with the file path you listed and then leverage the following example:

```
var imageFile = args.Files[0] as StorageFile;

// Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
    return bitmapImage;
}
```